# Maximal ideal $I$ in $R$ establishes a vector space of the field $R/I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R,S$ be commutative rings with unity s.t $R \subset S$.

Assume $I$ is a maximal ideal in $R$. Consider the ideal $IS$ in $S$.

I want to show that $S/IS$  is a vector space of the field $R/I$.

My attempt:

It suffices to show that $R/I$ is isomorphic to a subring of $S/IS$.

Define $\phi: R/I \to S/IS$ by $\phi(x + I) = x + IS$.

We have that $\phi(x+y+I) = (x+IS) + (y + IS) = \phi(x+I)+\phi(y+I)$, and $\phi(xy+I) = (x+IS)(y+IS) =\phi(x+I)\phi(y+I)$, so $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

We'll show that $\phi$ is injective to end;

Let $\phi(x+I) = 0_{S/IS}$.

If $x \notin I$, since $R/I$ is a field, $\exists \eta \in R/I$ s.t $(x+I)\eta = 1_{R/I} = 1 + I$.

Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism we have $\phi(x + I)\phi(\eta) = 0_{S/IS} = \phi(1+I) = 1 + IS$.

So if $1 \in IS$ the quotient $S/IS$ is the zero space and there is nothing to prove, else $x \in I$.

Is there a mistake in the above, does it suffice to prove that assertion?

Comment: It seems correct. so, $S/IS$ is actually a vector algebra over $R/I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof seems correct, but you're proving much more than it is required.

$I$ being maximal is irrelevant: $S/IS$ is in a natural way a module over $R/I$.

The trick is actually that if $M=S/IS$, then $IM=0$ and it is simpler to show that, whenever $M$ is an $R$-module with $IM=0$, then $M$ becomes a module over $R/I$. Also $IS$ is obviously an $R$-submodule of $S$, so $S/IS$ is an $R$-module.

The action is $(r+I)x=rx$, which is well defined, because if $r+I=r'+I$ then $r-r'\in I$, so $(r-r')x=0$ and therefore $rx=r'x$. The module axioms are readily verified.